# Changing Invoice Layout (OpenERP 7.0)

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openoffice.org

I'm trying to figure out how to change the layout of invoices and reports in OpenERP 7.0. I've read that I need to use a specific plugin with OpenOffice, and I believe that I've found it, but I can't get it to load properly. Loading the [plugin](https://www.odoo.com/apps/7.0/base_report_designer/) brings up multiple errors, and it won't install correctly. I'm using it with OpenOffice 4.1.3. Am I using the wrong plugin or OpenOffice version, or is it just broken permanently?

Comment: Please update your question with attempts steps, errors, any traceback etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed addons base_report_designer on your openerp?

if you have installed, you can go to Reporting>Configuration>Report Designer

[image: Report Designer]

And then follow the instruction.

I use OpenOffice 4.1.3 and Report Designer working properly.